# MySQL how to update a field where count by id DESC more than a value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table that stores some system info.
I'd like to make an update that set 0 a roll

```
UPDATE table set print='0' where user_id='98'
```

But I don't want to update all registry.
I need to leave intact the lasts 10 entries in db and sets 0 for 11th and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery to exclude the most recent 10 entries, as determined by some timestamp column:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET print = '0'
WHERE
    user_id = '98' AND
    id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM yourTable
                               WHERE user_id = '98'
                               ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10) x);
```

Comment: what is thet ´x´ ?

Comment: @JasarOrion The subquery needs to have an alias; `x` is the alias.

Comment: I am assuming that `id` is the primary key of your table.